# Hudson Running as a Service not Starting

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson

I downloaded Hudson, and am trying to install it as a service.  I followed the steps from [this page](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service), but when I try to start the service, it always fails.  I'm not really getting any defined error codes either.  If I try to run the service from the command line (using net start) I get the following (unhelpful) message:

The hudson service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

The install process seemed to work fine, as the hudson service is installed, and all the files are in the new directory, but the service won't start.  Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented on that page, they have a note of...

If a restart fails for some reason, check the output from Hudson, which is stored in the installation directory that you specified.

Is there anything to denote further errors?

Comment: I recently had an auto update fail. The log file @qat mentions indicated that the .war file was corrupt. Once I reinstalled that file manually, everything worked fine.

Comment: It actually didn't have any output in the installation directory.  I restored the .war file and it worked perfectly.  Funny thing is, I did that several times before....  But thanks a bunch!